# How can I get my list passed by url?

Tags: python, arrays, url, get, python-3.5

My problem is how to get my list back. The original is:

```
["tick", "tac", "too"]
```

I send it in the get response to my server, then I get this encoded url:

```
patient%5B%5D=tick&patient%5B%5D=tac&patient%5B%5D=too
```

After applying `parse`, I get the result bellow:

```
urllib.parse.unquote(f.url)
>> /?patient[]=tick&patient[]=tac&patient[]=too
```

But It is still not an array, does someone know a simple way to get my list from this url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you better here use a library to decodes the query string.

You can use the function `parse_qs` from `urlib.parse`:

```
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs('patient%5B%5D=tick&patient%5B%5D=tac&patient%5B%5D=too')
{'patient[]': ['tick', 'tac', 'too']}
```

So you can write:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

tictactoo = urllib.parse.parse_qs('patient%5B%5D=tick&patient%5B%5D=tac&patient%5B%5D=too')['patient[]']
```

then `tictactoo` is:

```
>>> tictactoo
['tick', 'tac', 'too']
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfectly what I search